# NSPredicate with OR returning error

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a problem with the following predicate:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(creatorUserRecordID == %@) OR (toUser == %@)", userId, userId];
```

When I use it in query `CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Message" predicate:predicate];` I have an error that says: 'CKException', reason: 'Unexpected expression'.

When I use these two seperately like this:

```
   NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(creatorUserRecordID == %@)", userId];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(toUser == %@)", userId];
```

And then performing query with one of these predicates it works fine. I also tried using NSCompoundPredicate but the result is always the same... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `CKQuery` lists all of the valid predicate syntax. Oddly, under "Basic compound predicates" it lists `NOT`, `AND`, and `&&`. `OR` and `||` are not listed and apparently are not supported for CloudKit query predicates.

Comment: What I found in documentation is: Basic Compound Predicates

AND, &&
Logical AND.
OR, ||
Logical OR.
NOT, !
Logical NOT. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: ok got it. CKQuery does not allow predicate with OR although NSPredicate does. my mistake. could you hint me how can I query CloudKit with OR?